# Reloading data causing tableview to "lag" while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am implementing infinite scrolling for my app. When the user reached the bottom of the tableview, I reload five more sets of data from the internet and update them in my dataArray before calling `myTableView.reloadData`. I am finding that if the user is scrolling (which more then likely is the case), the tableView will lag causing a poor UI experience.

I have also tried inserting the data to the tableView rather than reload the whole table. However, I am finding that ever since I change to using `estimatedSectionHeight` rather than calculating my own height to display, I am getting a huge delay around the `myTableView.insertSection` code

**My Code :**

```
myTableView.beginUpdates()
for post in downloadPosts {
    postsArray.append(post)
    let sections = NSIndexSet(index: postsArray.count - 1)
    myTableView.insertSections(sections, withRowAnimation: .None)
}
myTableView.endUpdates()
```

Is there a way to reload the data inside table without affecting the scrolling experience?

Comment: if your tableView is lagging, than you maybe do to much on the main thread. Means initialising the data for cells or whatever. If you use beginUpdates and endUpdates you dont need to reload the data. Because its done by them. Did you try to init your cells data without data? SO you can test if its still lagging. So everything that is happening in cellForRowAtIndexPath is commented out and maybe only one text is vissible.

Comment: Try Asynchronous loading for getting data from internet